# log-likelihood function generated by scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

The method `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit` finds the parameters that maximise a log likelihood function which is determined by the input data and the specification of the distribution `rv_continuous`. For instance, this could be `normal` or `gamma`.

The documentation for `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit` doesn't explain how the log-likelihood function is generated and I would like to know how. I need it so I can calculate the value of the log-likelihood at the parameters estimated by fit (i.e. the maximum value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log-likelihood is the logarithm of the probability that a given set of observations is observed given a probability distribution. You can access the value of a probability density function at a point `x` for your `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` member using `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf(x,params)`. You would take the product of these values for each member of your data, then take the log of that. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
m,s = norm.fit(data)
log_likelihood = np.log(np.product(norm.pdf(data,m,s)))
```

Comment: This answer is correct. An additional suggestion: you will get numerically more stable performance if you sum the logarithms rather than take the logarithm of the product. In code, do: `log_likelihood = np.sum(np.log(norm.pdf(data,m,s)))` instead of `log_likelihood = np.log(np.product(norm.pdf(data,m,s)))`. The reason for this is that multiplying many small numbers results in a very small number. Taking the logarithms, then summing, makes the range of the numbers you make computations with more manageable.

Answer (score 4):

While Mark's answer is technically correct, I can only re-iterate nikosd's concern from the comment - taking the product first and then logging it, will in many practical scenarios make your results unusable. If have many (thousands/millions) observations in `data`, each has a probability of <=1, so your product `np.product(norm.pdf(data,m,s))` will be very small and often smaller than numerical precision, making your results unstable/wrong.

Thus the better way - and the reason why log-likelihood is used in the first place -  is to first log the individual probabilities `np.log(norm.pdf(data,m,s))` and then sum over the resulting vector.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
m,s = norm.fit(data)
log_likelihood = np.sum(np.log(norm.pdf(data,m,s)))
```

I thought this was important enough to warrant a separate answer.